# Lie algebra cohomology of loop algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, lie-algebras, cohomology

Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over the complex numbers. Is it true that the Lie algebra cohomology $H^*(L\mathfrak{g}, \mathbb{C})$ of the loop Lie algebra $L\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathbb{C}((z))$ is isomorphic to the singular cohomology $H^*(LG, \mathbb{C})$ of the loop group of $G$?

I know that the corresponding statement is true for the real form of $G$. I.e. if we want to compute the Lie algebra cohomology for $\mathfrak{g}$ we can just compute the de Rham cohomology for $G$. However, the argument I know of this fact uses the averaging process on $G$ to get a left-invariant differential form from an ordinary differential form. Is there some other way of getting the isomorphism?

Comment: In defining $H^*(L\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{C})$, could you be more specific? Do you really mean Lie algebra cohomology, or do you have in mind some topological restriction using the topology of $\mathbf{C}((z))$? Indeed $H_2(L\mathfrak{g},\mathbf{C})$ is known (due to Bloch for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$) to be isomorphic to $\mathrm{HC}_1(A)=\Omega^1_{A/\mathbf{C}}/dA$, where $A=\mathbf{C}((z))$. Abstractly, this is a space of dimension continuum, so the dual $H^2$ has dimension $2^c$. But restricting to the continuous part of $\mathrm{HC}_1(A)$, i.e. continuous cocycles, makes it, I think, 1-dimensional.

Comment: @YCor I'm not sure. I'm working through the beginning of Frenkel's "Langlands Correspondence for Loop Groups" and he mentions that it's well known that for a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ that the second Lie algebra cohomology of $L\mathfrak{g}$ is one-dimensional. As far as I can tell he means the Lie algebra cohomology in the ordinary sense (taking $2$-cocycles modulo $2$-coboundaries). He mentions no restriction on the cocycles

Comment: So he's using a continuity assumption, or his statement is just wrong. Write $K=\mathbf{C}((z))$, let $W_K$ be the space of $\mathbf{C}$-linear maps $f:K\otimes K\to K$ such that $f(ab\otimes c+bc\otimes a+ca\otimes b)=f(a\otimes bc+b\otimes ca+c\otimes ab)$ for all $a,b,c$. If $u,v$ are $\mathbf{C}$-linear derivations of $K$, then $(a,b)\mapsto u(a)v(b)$ belongs to $W_K$, and it's easy to deduce that $W_K$ has at least continuum dimension (if no continuity assumption is made). More precisely is $B$ is a transcendence basis of $K$ over $\mathbf{C}$ (...)

Comment: (...) and $a\neq b\in B$ then there exists $f=f_{a,b}\in W_K$ such that $f(a\otimes b)=1$ and $f(c\otimes d)=0$ for all $(c,d)\in B^2-\{(a,b)\}$. Now map $\Lambda^2(\mathfrak{g}\otimes K)$ into $K$ by $ux\wedge vy\mapsto f(u\otimes v-v\otimes u)\langle x,y\rangle$, where $\langle .,.\rangle$ is the Killing form. This vanishes on 2-boundaries. Hence it defines a 2-cohomology class $q(f)$. Then, evaluating on the 2-cycles $ax\wedge by-bx\wedge ay$, one checks that the family $(q(f_{a,b}))$, $(a,b)\in B^2$, generates a subspace of continuum dimension in $H^2(\mathfrak{g}\otimes K)$.

Comment: PS: in this context $\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbf{C}[t,1/t]$ is sometimes also called the loop Lie algebra. In this case the statement about cohomology is correct: $H^2$ is 1-dimensional. PPS: in my previous two comments, $u,v$ mean two derivations in the first one, and two scalars in the second one, sorry.

Comment: @YCor I think I agree. If we take the loop algebra to be the tensor product of the Lie algebra with Laurent polynomials then things should work out as is. When passing to the formal completion some continuity condition should be imposed

Comment: How do you see in this case that $H^2$ is one dimensional?

Comment: I haven't checked that the continuous $H^2$ is 1-dimensional. Still, I guess it should follow with no major difficulty from the fact that $\mathbf{C}[z,1/z]$ is dense in $\mathbf{C}((z)$.